# not connecting to the database

Tags: php, sql-server

To connect mssql from my android application, I wrote the following script:

```
<?php
  $myServer= "*****";
  $myUser="*****";
  $myPass="***";
  $db="*****";

  echo "hi";
  $dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass);
  echo $dbhandle;
  if($dbhandle) {
    echo "success";
  } else {
    echo "failed";
  }
  $database = mssql_select_db($db);
?>
```

When I test it in a browser, it's showing only "hi" and it's not executing remaining lines of code.  What would be the problem here?

Comment: @Tudor Constantin: The code wasn't visible because it wasn't formatted -- see update

Comment: try to add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in the first line.

Comment: @tudor plese see the script now,,,somebody has edited...

Comment: maybe a good Ol' connect() or die(error()) will tell you what the problem is

Comment: mssql_get_last_message()

Comment: @dagon where to place that statement ..and what for it is?

Comment: If the script is actually dying, there should be something in the php error logs.

Comment: @Naresh rtfm - http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-get-last-message.php

Comment: put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in the first line as 0xAli suggested. It will show you the error that you are getting. Then, post the error message so we can see. Another thing is, are you saying that you are hosting it on a web server provider or your own server?

Comment: i am hosting that one into webserver provider

Comment: which webhosting is it? probably the webhosting doesn't support SQL Server.. mind sharing the link to the webhosting..

Comment: godaddy..but its supporting ms sql

Answer (score 0):

You have not enabled the mssql module in PHP. If you find the error logs, it would say something like "mssql_connect is not a function".

The mssql support built into PHP has been broken for some time. I would suggest following the instructions on [this page](http://docs.moodle.org/20/en/Installing_MSSQL_for_PHP) to help you get it configured.

Comment: Let me rephrase. PHP doesn't know what the mssql_connect function is because you have not enabled mssql in the PHP configuration.

Comment: i am a android developer..i don't know about php..how configure this function ..pls even though its not showing any error mesage